# How to connect via SSH to EC2 instance that got unreachable?

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh, amazon-ec2

Having an AWS EC2 instance running [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) for several years.

Since some weeks/months it occurs that after some Discourse upgrades (through the web GUI of Discourse), the system stalls. It is then not reachable via SSH anymore and not even via EC2 SSH web connect.

I ususally did a restart of the whole machine via the AWS ECS web admin panel and then was able to connect again, both via SSH and HTTPS.

(I did not further investigate the cause of the issue, unfortunately).

Today, the system hung again after a Discourse upgrade.

But this time, no reboot or whatsoever did help. The system stays unreachable via SSH, even after waiting for several hours.

The EC2 monitoring also shows no high server load to me:

[image]

#### My question

How can I gain access via SSH to the EC2 Ubuntu instance again?

#### Update 1

After yet another reboot and some wait time, the system is back again, out of nowhere again.

To me, it seems that the disk has enough free space (no more disk space was one of my assumptions why the system was unreachable).

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           394M  876K  393M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       97G   31G   67G  31% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/loop2       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop3       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
overlay          97G   31G   67G  31% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5a799ab040002ad2ddec94ae85bcbe987543651a0d9478ddc12ab12715da7340/merged
tmpfs           394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I'm now trying to figure out whether there are any logs that indicate the reason for the outage.

#### Update 2

As of request by heynnema, here is the full result of `sudo cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 06:a0:68:ea:54:4e
            set-name: eth0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thank you very much, @heynnema I've just updated my question.

Comment: Let me know if my answer solves your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Amazon AWS EC2 you need to use a .yaml like this. SSH will work then.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 06:a0:68:ea:54:4e
      set-name: eth0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: 06:a0:68:ea:54:4e
      interfaces:
        - eth0
```

---

**Note**: You may need to create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

---

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
reboot # mandatory
```

Check [this link](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html) for further information.

Comment: Thanks again! Just to be sure I understand your suggestion: When doing the above, this will _not_ disable my current SSH access via Putty (which is working again), but only _add_ the option to connection via the AWS EC2 admin panel with SSH. Correct?

Comment: @UweKeim I believe your understanding is correct... as you indicated that you lost *"not reachable via SSH anymore and not even via EC2 SSH web connect"*... but I'm certainly not an expert on AWS EC2. I just know that this .yaml has fixed a lot of SSH problems for other users.

Comment: @UweKeim Status please... did this work for you?

Comment: I've not implemented it yet, I'm still trying to figure out a way of finding log files to hopefully see the reason of why the machine gets unresponsive. After that, I'll try this (doing a snapshot before, just in case)